# Canvas project not properly rendering function

Tags: javascript, canvas, jquery-animate

I cannot seem to get my Rect to render in real time no matter how much I try. The player.update() method only seems to work when it's not nested in the animate function, cause when I put the player.update method in function animate() it straight up doesn't run

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')

const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

const gravity = 0.5
class Player{
    constructor() {
        this.position = {
            x: 100,
            y: 100
        }
        this.velocity = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
        this.width = 30
        this.height = 30
    }

    drawPlayer() {
        c.fillStyle = 'red'
        c.fillRect(
            this.position.x, 
            this.position.y, 
            this.width, 
            this.height
            )
    }
    update() {
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y
        this.drawPlayer()

        if (this.position.y + this.height + this.velocity.y <= canvas.height)
            this.velocity.y += gravity
        else this.velocity.y = 0
    }
}

const player = new Player()

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    console.log('go')
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    player.update()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Call `animate`

Sorry it's a boring answer, but it just simple looks like you're never actually starting your "game loop" of `animate()`. Seems fine otherwise.

<strike>Small concern. I would do the `requestAnimationFrame` last, otherwise it's just going to make a loop of calling itself over and over again. Chrome handled it well, but I'm not confident in other browsers (excluding firefox).</strike>

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')

const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

const gravity = 0.5
class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.position = {
      x: 100,
      y: 100
    }
    this.velocity = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
    this.width = 30
    this.height = 30
  }

  drawPlayer() {
    c.fillStyle = 'red'
    c.fillRect(
      this.position.x,
      this.position.y,
      this.width,
      this.height
    )
  }
  update() {
    this.position.y += this.velocity.y
    this.drawPlayer()

    if (this.position.y + this.height + this.velocity.y <= canvas.height)
      this.velocity.y += gravity
    else this.velocity.y = 0
  }
}

const player = new Player()

function animate() {
  //console.log('go')
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  player.update()
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)

}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is just fine where it was. It schedules a new callback, it doesn't call it.